# Adding scripting entitlements to entitlement plist in Xcode 6

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, scripting, entitlements

I am having trouble turning this xml provided by the mac developer library into the normal plist form used in the entitlements
The XML provided by mac developer library:

```
<key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.mail</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.apple.mail.compose</string>
    </array>
</dict>
```

I would post an image of my plist but I don't have enough rep to post images.

My main issue is I don't know what type/value to make the keys in my plist and what to put in the key column for the dict and array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Step 1 ) Add com.apple.security.scripting-targets and select type as dict
step 2 ) Inside above dictionary add com.apple.mail and select type as array
step 3) add com.apple.mail.compose inside the above array.

OR

you can simply open your plist as source code by right click the plist and select open as source code and just paste the The XML provided by mac developer inside it 

        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
    <plist version="1.0">
       <dict>
          <key>com.apple.security.scripting-targets</key>
          <dict>
             <key>com.apple.mail</key>
             <array>
                <string>com.apple.mail.compose</string>
             </array>
          </dict>
       </dict>
    </plist>
```